# How to copy the selected image from picture library to the images folder dynamically in the application?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am new to the windows phone 7 application development. I am accessing the picture library by using the PhotoChooserTask class. After selecting one of the picture from picture library I want to add that image (.jpg file) from picture library to the images folder of my application. How to do this ? I am using the following code

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {

        PhotoChooserTask photoChooserTask; 
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            photoChooserTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
            photoChooserTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(photoChooserTask_Completed); 
         }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            photoChooserTask.Show();            
        }

        void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
        {
            if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
            {
                BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
                bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

            }
        } 
    }
```

I want to add the the selected image dynamically to images folder of my application. how to do this? Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can resolve the above issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of saving the selected picture to IsolatedStorage and then reading it out to display it on the page:

```
void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        var contents = new byte[1024];

        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (var local = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("image.jpg", FileMode.Create, store))
            {
                int bytes;
                while ((bytes = e.ChosenPhoto.Read(contents, 0, contents.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    local.Write(contents, 0, bytes);
                }
            }

            // Read the saved image back out
            var fileStream = store.OpenFile("image.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            var imageAsBitmap = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(fileStream);

            // Display the read image in a control on the page called 'MyImage'
            MyImage.Source = imageAsBitmap;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the [RTM release notes](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CB8QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F1%2F7%2F7%2F177D6AF8-17FA-40E7-AB53-00B7CED31729%2FRelease%2520Notes%2520-%2520WPDT%2520RTM.htm&ei=shSUTJmkOJCjccq9kKQF&usg=AFQjCNFK6vjO9Ml8hg8QmNdwgDGCWl_XXw&sig2=7FMY4s2hhxRvitzDNFLRfQ) on the revised Photo Chooser API or the doco a bit further down the page here.

[How to: Create a Photo Extras Application for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff817010%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, once you obtain the stream, you can convert it to byte and store locally. Here is what you should have in your Task_Completed event handler:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    byte[] contents = new byte[1024];
    int bytes;

    while ((bytes = e.ChosenPhoto.Read(contents, 0, contents.Length)) > 0)
    {
        stream.Write(contents, 0, bytes);
    }

    using (var local = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("myImage.jpg", FileMode.Create, IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()))
    {
        local.Write(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, stream.GetBuffer().Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI. You don't need to create a separate MemoryStream to do this. Plus your code doesn't dispose of the IsolatedStorageFile returned by GetUserStoreForApplication().