# Dispaly image from media library to imagesBox in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing app for windows phone, where i am taking screenshot and all these screenshot are saving in media library,Now my aim is to retrieve all images from media library and display them in ImageBox one by one by clicking button , Please help how can i do this .
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the photo from the `MediaLibrary` and then save it to the `Isolated Storage` or else as you said you could display it in an `image` control.

```
private void Pick_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var pc = new PhotoChooserTask();
   pc.Completed += pc_Completed;
   pc.Show();
} 

void pc_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    var originalFilename = Path.GetFileName(e.OriginalFileName);
    SaveImage(e.ChosenPhoto, originalFilename, 0, 100);
}

public static void SaveImage(Stream imageStream, string fileName, int orientation, int quality)
{
    using (var isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        if (isolatedStorage.FileExists(fileName))
            isolatedStorage.DeleteFile(fileName);

        var fileStream = isolatedStorage.CreateFile(fileName);
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.SetSource(imageStream);

        var wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
        wb.SaveJpeg(fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, orientation, quality);
        fileStream.Close();
    }
}
```

You could have a look at here too: [How to copy the selected image from picture library to the images folder dynamically in the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253438/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi anonshankar Thank, but i am getting error in line Path.GetFileName(e.OriginalFileName), help me why i am getting this error.

Comment: there you could give the path of the file.